PIR Circuit Problem
I am using D203B model of PIR and I used the circuit that was suggested on its datasheet (first pic). I do not know what the problem is, as the output (pin the 8 and 14) of op-amp (LM324)is always on (which is connected to the transistor and LED). In fact, It does not react based on PIR output as I disconnected the PIR from op-amp and the output of op-amp was still on. By the way, I have checked LM324 and it was healthy so problem is in my circuit.
Here are my circuit schematic and PCB (2nd and 3rd pics). I appreciate you, if you realize the problem.



edit: here is the datasheet file:
http://server4.eca.ir/eshop/datasheets/PIR/0404011.pdf

Saeed - Hi, Regarding the image you copied from the datasheet: To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add each name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). (When the original source is a book or other offline material, please see the linked rule for details.) TY

Please fix the reference issue and clarify which of the 4 outputs you are referring to.

@SamGibson, I edited the question, could you please give your opinion?

@SpehroPefhany, I shared the datasheet link and edited the question. I appreciate you helping me.

What happens when you measure the S pin of the PIR sensor and pin 1 of the LM324? This is called signal tracing. Start at the source and trace the progress through the circuit (to the extent you have tools to measure it).  Don't forget the Fresnel lens to get the PIR to work properly (and to give it some signal).

@SpehroPefhany S pin of sensor is around 0.8 which i think is normal. Next, I should say there is a problem in the first V ref (pin2) as I have no stable signal on it so first v out (pin 1) is zero.

I had made a mistake in soldering and c9 had not connected to the track of pin 2 so there was not v ref now it is solved.
Now how can I make the time and also sensivity of output adjustable ?
